# Is it possible to create a List<class> where class is reflected at runtime?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

So let's say I use reflection to find a class'subtypes (I'm using the Google Reflections library).

```
Set<Class<? extends Parent>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Parent.class);
```

now I want to create a list for each subtype, by iterating over the set's members, so I want something like this:

```
try {
    for (Class<? extends Parent> cType : subTypes.iterator()) {
        Class x = Class.forName(cType.getName());
        List<x> list = new ArrayList<x>();
    }
} catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
    ...
}
```

However, this doesn't work, and the compiler complains that 'x is an unknown class' on the list definition.

Is there a way to define a list based on the reflected types?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the list before returning it from your utility?

Comment: To answer the question, no, it's not possible.

Comment: `Class x = Class.forName(cType.getName());`:  How is `x` different from `cType`?  Are you trying to load different classes with the same name in two different class loaders?

Comment: Why would you want this? Expand your example to show how you'll use `list`. It's likely that your true goal is probably achievable, but you've jumped to conclusions about how to reach it.

Comment: The reason for doing this is: I have a number of classes that inherit from Parent, and more of these can be added as time goes by.  In this method, I need to create a list for each subtype, as I get a master list of all the subtypes, and I need to partition it based on subtype.  I'd love to hear alternate solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define

```
<T> static List<T> listForType(Class<T> elementType) {
  return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

and then you might try

```
Class<X> xClass = cType;
List<X> listOfX = listForType(xClass);
```

but there's no way for the language to manufacture an invariant type parameter `X` from a variant type parameter `? extends Parent` in a type-safe manner.

---

If you do have an invariant type elsewhere, you might be able to get type-safe code by limiting the unchecked code to a small place as long as your sub-types are not themselves parameterized types.

```
final class ListPerSubType {
  private final Map<Class<? extends Parent>, List> listPerSubType = new LinkedHashMap<>();

  public <T extends Parent> List<T> get(Class<T> cl) {
    // TODO: throw IllegalArgument if cl is parameterized.
    if (!listPerSubType.containsKey(cl)) {
      listPerSubType.put(cl, new ArrayList<T>());
    }
    List list = listPerSubType.get(cl);
    // This is type-safe since no other code exposes the
    // lists via type not gained from a type token.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<T> typedList = list;
    return list;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to use a reflected type as a type parameter in Java. This is also of no use, because Java generics are useful only at compile time; once the compiler has finished, generic class instances on different type parameters become identical due to type erasure.

This means that the code which uses a reflected type for a generic parameter would not be any more useful than a code with generic parameter substituted for the parent interface (i.e. `List<Parent>` in your case) or  `List<Object>` when there is no common base class / interface.

Comment: In addition to this answer, this post on [type erasure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens) should help.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have this part working:

```
Set<Class<? extends Parent>> subTypes = 
    reflections.getSubTypesOf(Parent.class);
```

I think if you make the changes shown here, you will resolve your problem:

```
public <P extends Parent> void handleSubTypes(Set<Class<P>> subTypes) {
    try {
        for (Class<P> sType : subTypes) {
            P instance = sType.newInstance();
            List<P> list = new ArrayList<P>();
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And here is a cut from the `Class.newInstance()` JavaDoc:

> Creates a new instance of the class represented by this Class object.
>   The class is instantiated as if by a new expression with an empty
>   argument list. The class is initialized if it has not already been
>   initialized. Note that this method propagates any exception thrown by
>   the nullary constructor, including a checked exception. Use of this
>   method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that
>   would otherwise be performed by the compiler. The
>   Constructor.newInstance method avoids this problem by wrapping any
>   exception thrown by the constructor in a (checked)
>   InvocationTargetException.